# Loopback: registerResolver doesn't fire on all requests to API except user model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to `registerResolver('$everyone', function(role, ctx. cb){...})` from boot script to check roles of user and restrict access to some data. But this works only with `/user` endpoint. When I try to access to data of some another model registerResolver doesn't work. 
What I'm doing wrong?

**UPD**
Resolver has started to work after I had added ACLs to `my-model.json`. But why it doesn't work without ACL?

Answer (score 0):

ACL is basically a gatekeeper between this and the loopback model methods. Any incoming request will be checked to identify who makes the call (appId, userId, deviceId, etc). This is why it is needed in this instance.

Comment: I understand what the ACL is. My question was how to force registerResolver to work without writing acls to model.json? I want all my acls to be in database.

Answer (score 0):

If the model doesn't have ACL, there is no reason to check the users roles, as there is nothing to match against. User has ACL by default, which is why it triggers.

Also, overloading the $everyone-role is probably a bad idea. Based on what you are trying to achieve, I think a afterremote hook is probably better for your usecase.